# R - apply / mapply - Transpose is Required

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I have defined a R function that takes 2 strings as input, and returns 10 columns as output. With a sample function to explain the issue -

```
func.ret.10.cols = function(x,y) {
# process strings ... yada yada
.....
# process strings ... yada yada
return ( cbind(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
}
```

Testing this with a Data Frame -

```
> df1
                                    V1                                   V2
1 741 zulu zulu street 71 15 41 510741 741 14 21 zulu zulu street 71 510742
2 741 zulu zulu street 71 15 41 510741 741 14 21 zulu zulu street 71 510742

> str(df1)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "741 zulu zulu street 71 15 41 510741" "741 zulu zulu street 71 15 41 510741"
 $ V2: chr  "741 14 21 zulu zulu street 71 510742" "741 14 21 zulu zulu street 71 510742"
>
```

Now when i call this function, i expect to get a output of 10 columns and 2 rows. However i always get 2 columns and 10 rows.

```
> apply(df1[,c('V1','V2')], 1, function(x) func.ret.10.cols(x[1],x[2]))
       1  2
 [1,]  1  1
 [2,]  2  2
 [3,]  3  3
 [4,]  4  4
 [5,]  5  5
 [6,]  6  6
 [7,]  7  7
 [8,]  8  8
 [9,]  9  9
[10,] 10 10
> mapply(function(x,y) func.ret.10.cols(x,y), df1$V1, df1$V2)
      741 zulu zulu street 71 15 41 510741 741 zulu zulu street 71 15 41 510741
 [1,]                                    1                                    1
 [2,]                                    2                                    2
 [3,]                                    3                                    3
 [4,]                                    4                                    4
 [5,]                                    5                                    5
 [6,]                                    6                                    6
 [7,]                                    7                                    7
 [8,]                                    8                                    8
 [9,]                                    9                                    9
[10,]                                   10                                   10
```

I also tried with as.data.frame(cbind(1,2,3....)), but still got the same.
Is there something that i am missing.

Although its easy enough to use a t(apply(...), I just want to know what have i overlooked.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look at the documentation (`?apply`)

> If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN]) if n > 1.

In other words: The number of rows of the resulting matrix is given by the length of the vectors in your function to be applied.

Comment: Thanks. So transpose is necessary for apply and mapply to map it back to the original dataset